# How to identify latest version of data in MarkLogic Database

Tags: marklogic

I am receiving data from source in different intervals to MarkLogic Staging Database.Apache Nifi processor is creating the URI with UUID so I am getting Duplicate data in Staging Database and its causing issues while running Harmonization. I need to keep only the latest ingested record and delete the old version of data before running harmonization

I have tried xdmp:document-timestamp to identify the latest ingested record but it is impacting the performance. I need an optimal solution for fixing this issue(note: I cannot modify the URI is coming from Apache Nifi due to some dependency)

Comment: What do you have that uniquely identifies the documents and their versions? Can you post an example of a doc and what elements or field values are unique to the docs that have multiple versions?

Comment: And what do you have that would indicate a "version" or dateTime of ingest?

Comment: If you ingest the same data repeatedly and only need the latest copies, having fixed URIs might be better than UUID.

Comment: <BillData>
  <BillNo>123<BillNo>
  <Description>ABC<Description>
  <Item1><Item1>
  <Item2><Item2>
</BillData> My XML look like this and BillNo is the primary Key for a document. If I add BillNo in my URI it will resolve the issue but its not possible due to some other constraints also same BillNo data is ingesting to the database. I am looking for an alternative function for xdmp:document-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing ingest job is just a firehose that inserts and you want to cleanup dups after the fact?

You can get a sequence of the distinct `BillNo` values:

```
let $values := cts:values(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("BillNo")))
```

You can query for docs by the `BillNo`, order by the document property `prop:last-modified` (if enabled) or `xdmp:document-timestamp()`, and delete all but the first ordered document.

```
for $doc at $i in cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("BillNo"), "=", $billNo))
let $uri := $doc/base-uri()
where $i gt 1
(:order by $doc/property::prop:last-modified descending:)
order by xdmp:document-timestamp($uri) descending
return 
  xdmp:document-delete($uri)
```

If you have many docs, this could take a while and be a really large transaction. So, instead of doing all the work in one transaction, you can split it up.

You could spawn the work with [`xdmp:spawn-function()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:spawn-function) and try using the task server.

```
let $values := cts:values(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("BillNo")))
for $billNo in $values
return
  xdmp:spawn-function(function(){
    for $doc at $i in cts:search(doc(), cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("BillNo"), "=", $billNo))
    let $uri := $doc/base-uri()
    where $i gt 1
    order by xdmp:document-timestamp($uri) descending
    return
      xdmp:document-delete($uri) 
  })
```

However, you would be limited to the capacity of that one E-node (spawn only puts work onto it's own server, and doesn't take advantage of the rest of the nodes in the cluster to spread out the work).

This type of work is a great candidate for a [CoRB job](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2), in which the work is fanned out and performed in a multi-threaded fashion.

For such a CoRB job, select the distinct list of `BillNo` values in the URIs query:

```
let $values := cts:values(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("BillNo")))
return (count($values), $values)
```

and use that value to perform the work for a particular `BillNo` in the process module:

```
declare variable $URI as xs:string external;

(: you could also use a range-query, 
   but would have to convert the string value to an appropriate numeric type :)
for $doc at $i in cts:search(doc(), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("BillNo"), $URI))
let $uri := $doc/base-uri()
where $i gt 1
order by xdmp:document-timestamp($uri) descending
return
  xdmp:document-delete($uri)
```